# C++ MySQL Linker errors

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2010, boost

I am new to Visual C++. I wanted to work with MySQL/C++. 
So, I

- Installed MySQL on my machine Installed VS 2010 Professional on my
  machine
- From the internet, I found that My SQL drivers are found in

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\include  <-- Headers
>
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.C++ 1.1\lib      <-- Libs

- I made a sample program, which I copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424828/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-c).
- Build the project
- Got errors related to boost
- Downloaded Boost from [Download boost_1_61_0.7z (74.8 MB)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)
- Unzipped the archive
- Added Include path using **Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories**

[image]

- Added Linker additional libraries using **Project Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories**

[image]

- Built the Project
- Now it fails with below errors

> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const & __thiscall
>   sql::SQLException::getSQLState(void)const "
>   (__imp_?getSQLState@SQLException@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function __catch$_wmain$0
>
> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int
>   __thiscall sql::SQLException::getErrorCode(void)const " (__imp_?getErrorCode@SQLException@sql@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function
>   __catch$_wmain$0 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function _wmain
>
> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)"
>   (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function _wmain
>
> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function _wmain
>
> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const & __thiscall
>   sql::SQLString::asStdString(void)const "
>   (__imp_?asStdString@SQLString@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<<(class
>   std::basic_ostream > &,class
>   sql::SQLString const &)"
>   (??6std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@ABVSQLString@sql@@@Z)

[image]

**Please help. I am totally stuck**

**Edit:**

This line is causing below error

```
cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
```

> 1>DemoDB.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const & __thiscall
>   sql::SQLException::getSQLState(void)const "
>   (__imp_?getSQLState@SQLException@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function __catch$_wmain$0

I have referred below so far, but no help

- [C++ MySQL Linker Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537637/c-mysql-linker-error)
- [C++ mySQL connector LINKER errors (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470721/c-mysql-connector-linker-errors--) windows
- [How do I add additional libraries in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445418/how-to-add-additional-libraries-in-c)
- [MySQL C++ Connector unresolved external symbol _get_driver_instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168138/mysql-c-connector-unresolved-external-symbol-get-driver-instance)

Comment: Perhaps the MySQL drivers you installed were from a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @drescherjm I downloaded MySQL from this link (v5.7.14). How can I know the compatibility for MySQL for Visual Studio ?  Link --> http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-community-5.7.14.0.msi

Comment: Does the MySQL library that your are using have automatic linking using a pragma?

Comment: @drescherjm I believe it has because even though i am not using #pragma my lib is being linked. I solved this defining preprocessor macro "CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC="

Comment: If this is solved you should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

> I managed to solve this, after a lot of struggle. Below is what helped
>   me

- First, went to **Project Properties > Configuration Manager > "Created new configuration for Platform x64**, as my MySQL library was 64-bit

[image]

- Second, went to **Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories** and **included path for MySQL C++ Connector & MySQL Connector C**

[image]

- Third, went to **Project Properties > Linker > General > Additional Libraries Directories** and **added path for MySQL C++ connector**

[image]

- Fourth, went to **Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies** and **added *mysqlcppcon.lib***

[image]

After all this, built the project and **it ran fine ! :)**

[image]